# Где физически хранятся данные из базы данных в docker контейнере?

Tags: база-данных, docker

Намереваюсь поднять базу данных в docker (neo4j но тип базы данных не имеет значения в моем вопросе) для своего pet-проекта. Ранее docker не использовал. Не могу понять, если запустить базу данных в контейнере и постепенно данные будут заполняться пользователями моего приложения, то где физически эти данные будут храниться. Я верно понимаю, что "volume" именно для этого и предназначено, а лимит хранения данных ограничен доступным объемом памяти сервера, на котором запущен контейнер?

Comment: Что имеется ввиду под "физически"?

Comment: Я имею ввиду сами записи. Например по логике приложения, создан новый пользователь, произведена запись в базу с его логином, паролем и т.д. Где эти записи хранятся когда, например контейнер остановлен? Не в оперативной же памяти.

Comment: удивительно, но данные из базы хранятся в самой базе. Следовательно, там где физически хранится ваша база там и хранятся записи. Если база в контейнере, то и записи в контейнере. Если база на сетевом диске, то и записи на сетевом диске. и т п

Comment: @Эникейщик напрашивается логичный вопрос — где докер физически хранит базу?

Comment: @andreymal я там добавил. Автору виднее, где его база. Мож в этом же контейнере, а может на сервере амазона.

Comment: В моем случае контейнер запускается на арендованном VPS. Неясен вопрос, с сохранностью данных, если контейнер останавливается например из-за сбоя. Что происходит с записями в б.д. Они тоже пропадают?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос разбивается на две части.

1. База данных лежит в файловой системе. Где именно зависит от базы данных и параметров конфигурации этой базы. Пример - postgres. По-умолчанию СУБД в контейнере хранит базы в `/var/lib/postgresql/data`
2. Теперь о физике. Где именно будет находится каталог `/var/lib/postgresql/` в вашем контейнере зависит от того как вы создадите/запустите контейнер. У `docker run` есть [опция `-v`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) которая указывает докеру отмапить каталог хоста в путь в контейнере.

Если создать контейнер с постгресом вот так:

```bash
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 \
  --name postgres-inside postgres
```

то физически данные будут лежать внутри контейнера.

Если же создать контейнер с постгресом вот так:

```bash
docker run -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -p 5432:5432 \
  -v /home/user/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data --name postgres-outside postgres
```

то физически данные будут лежать вне контейнера, в каталоге `/home/user/data` хостовой файловой системы.

Comment: Вот, я за это и спрашиваю. т.е. независимо от названия базы данных и параметров ее конфигурации, чтобы данные (записи в б.д.) были так сказать "persistant", их нужно "промапить" в volume с помощью опции -v о которой вы упомянули. Это и будет фактическим (или физическим) местом хранения всех записей, в случае остановки контейнера. Верно?

Comment: @АлександрСосо да, верно.